# div height 100% not working - I want to display background color at full height

Tags: html, colors, background, height

I have searched with no success...

I cannot get the DIV background color to span the height of the content

Here is the site, I put the word 'testing' just to see a peek of the color:

http://learn.rupertport.com/?port_plan=grain-on-the-move

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks - Niki

Comment: which background are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the green colour background

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that the DIV has a parent element with no defined height.

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
  <div id="PA-thumb">
    <div class="clearpathumb">testing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you need to give either element  "PA-thumb" or element "content"  a defined height in order to have the ‘testing’ DIV be able to fill it. I download the webpage and was able to get it to fill to 100% if I give one of the other elements a height.

Comment: Maybe I am trying to do something impossible.  It worked just as you said (PA-thumb with a defined height)....but I am looking to have the height adjust to have the colour bar display from top to footer - no matter how long the page content is (some pages will be shorter pages - some longer)